# Laravel Auth registration Redirect to Home Page

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5.1

I have login registration form which is built in auth.Every think is working properly. In Registration form Suppose if i enter plus(+) symbol  in email like `vision+name@gmail.co`m then it will directly redirecting to home page without confirmation of email.Can any one tell how to fix that issue

**Updated**

1.i try to register using email address without symbol then it will redirect confirmation email page

2.if i use plus symbol in email then ti will directly go to home page

**Updated 2**

1.suppose think that i have email valid address like vision@gmail.com .using this email address if i try to register then it will redirect to confirm email address page and user will get email

2.suppose think that i have email entered email address like vision+nsgs@gmail.com then it will directly goto home page

**Updated 3**

```
if (isset($res->userDetails->status) && $res->userDetails->status == true){                 
                Auth::loginUsingId($res->userDetails->id);

                return redirect (App::getLocale().'/confirmregister');
            }else if (isset($res->errrorCode) && $res->errrorCode==1) { 

            exit;
                return redirect()
                    ->back()
                    ->withInput()
                    ->withErrors(['error' => 'this is error')]);
            }

        }else
        {
            return redirect('/auth/login');
        }
```

i have printed $res before `Auth::loginUsingId($res->userDetails->id);` and am getting data .it looks like loginUsingId is having issue but i dont know exactly what is the issue.this is handled by old employee

```
stdClass Object
(
    [id] => 1030
    [firstname] => john
    [lastname] => doe
    [email] => john+as@gmail.com
    [password] => $2y$10$tHnUeRWb6kUmIxIgOpLP4e04rK7tt6cnhfvlHSL5T.wxAeFGZ95G.
    [role] => 0
    [confirm] => 0
    [status] => 1
)
```

this output i am getting before Auth::loginUsingId($res->userDetails->id); inside if

Comment: Are you saying that it is skipping validation and registration and logging them in? What version of Laravel are you using?

Comment: ya ur right .laravel 5.0.*

Comment: if i enter email without plus symbol then it will redirect to login or else directly goto home page

Comment: If you are on a registration page and enter an email without a plus symbol, does it go through the process of registering the user? In what cases does it redirect them to login and not register the user and then redirect them to the home page? Are you using an custom middleware?

Comment: @dericcain.updated question

Comment: When you say, "without confirmation of email", is this an email confirmation field or an email that is sent to the user's email address?

Comment: @dericcain.updated my question

Comment: Thanks for updating. Is the redirect method something you wrote or is it straight out of the box from Laravel's with scaffolding?

Comment: @dericcain.some registration modification done.for adding captcha

Comment: That would be where I would look. Maybe you could post your redirect method, or any other code that you may think would be relevant. I'm not thinking this is normal behavior on a fresh install because it would have been addressed by now.

Comment: @dericcain. i have updated code

Comment: When you add a `+` you are always getting the else part of this logic. That makes me question what the `status` of the user is. Can you put a `dd($res->userDetails->status)` right after the `else` and see what you get?

Comment: @dericcain.updated.but in else i am not getting any think

Comment: even i printed auth::user() after Auth::loginUsingId($res->userDetails->id);  .i  am getting value

Comment: I believe you should because you are logged in. Look at the 'Auth::loginUsingId'. That's got to be what is causing the redirect to the home page when a plus sign is used.

Comment: ya ur right.is it possble to sned email to vision@gmail.com suppose if i enter vision+sdgs@gmail.com alias

Comment: Sorry for the delay. You could setup an email alias but that would be accomplished through gmail and not Laravel, unless you did some type of regex function.

Comment: Hi can you proivde regex function in answer so i can accept your answer.Thanks a lot for your long time to post your comment

Comment: Unfortunately, I am not that great at using Regex 

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/125803/discussion-between-vision-and-dericcain).